# Javascript, Array first letter get from letter to letter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of names from A-Z in ABC order and I want to get all the names from A to J. Is there any way to do this besides checking the first letter of each character against an array of all the letters from A to J?

Example:

```
    var array=['Amy','Dolly','Jason','Madison','Patricia'];
```

And I want an array of Amy, Dolly and Jason.

Comment: you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

Comment: If it's sorted in alphabetical order, you can use binary search until you find the filrst name starting with 'K' and cut the array off at that point.

Comment: @KjellIvar there might not be a name with the letter K

Comment: Ah, yes that is true. And I guess it might not be any with J either. Maybe filter is your best bet then

Comment: in ff/es6/ployfills:`['Amy','Dolly','Jason','Madison','Patricia'].findIndex(/./.test, /^[K-Z]/)` would return the boundary without iterating all the values (unless there were no matches)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function like

```
var array=['Amy','Dolly','Jason','Madison','Patricia'];

var filtered = array.filter(function(el){return el[0]>='A' && el[0]<='J'})
```

```js
var array=['Amy','Dolly','Jason','Madison','Patricia'];

var filtered = array.filter(function(el){return el[0]>='A' && el[0]<='J'});

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(array) + '<br />' + JSON.stringify(filtered);
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Code above checking all element in array, if you want avoid it and array already sorted, you can use simple *for* loop

```
var array=['Amy','Dolly','Jason','Madison','Patricia'];
var result=[];

for(var i=0;i<len=array.length; i<len && (array[i][0]>='A' && array[i][0]<='J'); i++){
    result.push(array[i]);
}
```

or same in one liner

```
for(var i=0, result=[], len=array.length; i<len && (array[i][0]>='A' && array[i][0]<='J');result.push(array[i]),i++);
```

in `result` - filtered collection;

Yet another way find index and then use *slice* like

```
for(var i=0, len=array.length; i<len && (array[i][0]>='A' && array[i][0]<='J');i++);
var result = array.slice(0,i);
```

Interesing way from @dandavis in comment with *filter* and *regex*

```
var filtered = array.filter(/./.test, /^[A-J]/);
```

it altervative for

```
var regex = /^[A-J]/;
var filtered = array.filter(function(el){ return regex.test(el); });
```

Comment: that still iterates all the array values... might  use `.filter(/./.test, /^[A-J]/)` to avoid the custom...

Comment: @dandavis, _filter_ anyway will be check all elements

Comment: as say naive [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/get-element-from-ordered-array) fastest - for loop with slice :-)

Comment: i meant compared to [].findIndex(), which would stop at the first match, so it wouldn't have to iterate all. good review btw.  if you want perf and functionality , use _.filter() instead of [].filter with your custom functions, it executes much faster than native.

Comment: @dandavis, i not sure, but i think that `_.filter()` inside use native _filter_

Comment: i'm positive it does not. it doesn't even follow the same steps as native, ex `_.filter(Array(3), alert)` vs `Array(3).filter(alert)` that's how it faster: by doing less work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80928/discussion-between-grundy-and-dandavis).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ascii-value of the character and use a filter to get the result you want. The character code value of "J" is 74 and for "A" it is 65.

```
array.filter(function(v) { return v.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && v.charCodeAt(0) <= 74 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using regular expression..

```
   var array=['Amy','Dolly','Jason','Madison','Patricia'];
    var reg = new RegExp('^[A-J]');
    var arrTemp=[];
    var intLength = array.length;

    for(var i=0;i<intLength ;i++){ 
        if(reg.test(array[i])) { 
            arrTemp.push(array[i])
        }
    }

    console.log(arrTemp)
```

If you want consider case-sesitive nature then you can write your regular expression like

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[A-Ja-j]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['Amy', 'Dolly', 'Jason', 'Madison', 'Patricia'],
    bound = { lower: 'A', upper: 'J' },
    newArray = [],
    i = 0, j, l = array.length;
// lookup for the first element of the array which is smaller than the lower bound
while (i < l && array[i][0] < bound.lower) {
    i++;
}
j = i;
// lookup for the end of the upper bound and skip the rest
while (j < l && array[j][0] <= bound.upper) {
    j++;
}
// build new array
newArray = array.slice(i, j);
```